# Проблема со списком select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Есть select список

```
<select class="form-control" id="roleFilter" name="role.id"
                  ng-options="role.name for role in vm.roleSelectOptions"
                  ng-model="vm.selectedRole"
                  ng-change="vm.onRoleChange(vm.selectedRole)"><option ng-change="" value="">Выбор роли</option>
          </select>
```

Его начальный элемент(первый в списке) = самой первой роли. Как сделать так, чтобы первый в списке был элемент который очищал бы отфильтрованный список в начальное положение, он уже есть через option это "выбор роли" но не наделен функционалом, нужно сделать так чтобы при выборе он очищал получается списки и фильтры возвращал в исходное положение.
Контроллер написан на ангуляре который собственно и выводит список:

```
function onRoleChange(option) {
          vm.filter.useRoleFilter = (option !== vm.roleSelectOptions[0]);
          vm.filter.roleFilter = option.id;
          search(true);
        }
```

Можно конечно сделать через кнопку функционал к ней уже написал:

```
function defaultRole() {
      vm.filter.roleFilter = null;
      vm.filter.useRoleFilter = false;
      search(true);
    }
```

Она справляется на ура, но когда она фильтрует то в select списке как была выбрана роль так и остается, а id роли по которой фильтруется становится null но роль не изменяется. Наверное сложно но сейчас на примере попробую объяснить понятным языком: Из списка select выбирается допустим роль менеджер, по этой роли происходит фильтрация пользователей с такой ролью, и выводится их список. Когда нажимаю на кнопку выводится изначальный не отфильтрованный список, но в списке роль поле так и остается менеджер.

Поэтому надо как-нибудь через option добавить начальную строку типа "Выбор роли" и при выборе на нее вызывался бы функционам кнопки. Вот в этом проблема коротко говоря, непонимаю как реализовать. Пробовал через ng-change="defaultRole", но тогда список даже не вылазиет. Вооот, кто шарит и знает помогите пожалуйста!)))

Answer (score 0):

За выбранную роль отвечает ng-model="vm.selectedRole"
Измените значение этой переменной и будет вам счастье
Например vm.selectedRole = null;